# Causes of undetermined "ERROR sending record" in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

While running a Kafka Streams application, I see in the logs the following messages, that cause the thread to die.

```
ERROR task [1_14] Error sending record (key {"field":"somevalue","uid":"othervalue"}\x00\x00\x01b\x9Fm\xD4\xFD\x00\x00\x01b\x9F,\x04m value [91, 123, 34, 115, ...
```

The value is printed in several lines of the log, and comprises here 8 lines of 64K each, from a big message. However I have set my `max.message.bytes` limit on brokers to 5M, so it should be accepted.

Upon restart of the task, the same problem happens, so this message seems to be acting as a `poison pill`. A restart using a different `application.id` works, so network problems can be discarded.
I don't see anything in the brokers' logs that show a problem here, other than membership failing:

```
Member app-09987332-a834-4a70-9dde-2970047a5b01-StreamThread-1-consumer-f01836e1-6edf-4b87-b40d-ef0e8baf4d51 in group app has failed, removing it from the group
```

What can be causing this problem?
Kafka brokers 2.3.0, Kafka Streams 2.1.1.

Comment: `Error sending record` is not very descriptive. What is the actual problem, ie, exception / root cause?

Comment: There was not an additional root cause exposed in Kafka Streams logs. I agree it is not very descriptive. My `uncaughtExceptionHandler` prints the stack trace, but this one was not shown there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was due to too big a message.
The logs in AWS cut lines and do strange jumps in lines numbering sometimes.